# Get the time span of a time series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm trying to get the time span per group of entries (time series). The entries are not ordered. Is there a more efficient way to do this in pandas than using max-min? I've tried the timedelta and period functions and they don't return what I need.

```
import pandas as pd
tt = pd.DataFrame([
[1,'2018-3-1' ],
[1,'2018-2-3' ],
[1,'2018-5-2' ],
[1,'2018-4-5' ],
[2,'2017-3-10' ],
[2,'2017-1-12' ],
[2,'2017-5-15' ],
[2,'2017-2-14' ]
],columns=['group','entry'])

tt.entry = pd.to_datetime(tt.entry)

tt.groupby('group')['entry'].apply(lambda x: max(x)-min(x))

# group
# 1    88 days
# 2   123 days
# Name: entry, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way `ptp` from `numpy`

```
tt.groupby('group')['entry'].apply(np.ptp)
Out[773]: 
group
1    88 days
2   123 days
Name: entry, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: I get `DatetimeIndex cannot perform the operation ptp`

Comment: @RBA how about `tt.groupby('group')['entry'].apply(pd.Series.ptp)
`

Comment: got the same error with `tt.groupby('group')['entry'].apply(pd.Series.ptp)`
Pandas 0.24.2

Comment: @RBA I believe this is issue with pandas , I will submit it on git

Comment: Thanks! In which pandas version were you able to run np.ptp? I'll downgrade in a separate env to see if it improves performance for me

Comment: @RBA mine is 0.23.4

Comment: this is working well as of pandas >1